# How to enter debug mode without reloading the hex file?

Tags: debugging, hex, keil

For keil, each time when I select the menu "Debug --> Start/Stop Debug Session", the IDE would do the following actions:

1. reload the hex file into the target device's flash
2. reboot the target device and enter the debug mode

Now How to skip step 1 and do step 2 directly?
Because step 1 costs much time.

I mean, even if the current hex being generated by keil is different from the one in the target's flash, I want to skip step 1. Consider the scenario that the modification is only a space addition in a C source file, so actually the content of both hex files is nearly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Found it.
Go to the menu: Project →Options →Utilities, then unselect "Update target before Debugging".